# Value of hidden field is lost after loading the page in html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want a scenario in which I will set some value of a hidden field in a particular page.
Then that page is submitted on server (form submit). Now, i redirect on another page and there I again try to retrieve the value which I set previously. But I am not getting there the value which was set, instead i get the default value which I provided in html page itself. (Hidden field is in header page which is common for all the pages in my web app).

i tried a dummy application in which i am getting the value of hidden field even after loading/refreshing the page once i set it.

Comment: Without providing more information, it's hard for us to tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: How are setting the value of the hidden field? Can you show some code?

Comment: Some code examples would be great. You provide no information on how to store and retrieve the data between loads? Do you post it to a database, store it in a cookie, ...?

Comment: @Thor Not using database nor cookie.Actually my aim is to preserve the content of the hidden field throughout the application.instead of setting it cookie i am setting it to hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirected your user to another page, it became **reloaded**. Unless you chose to set a value to your form (by javascript for instance), the value of the form is the default one.

The value you "*set previously*" wasn't definitely associated to the input because everytime you reload the page, your server will generate again the HTML and the default values and your browser will display this HTML.

This behavior is **normal**.

Besides, if you want to *keep the values* of the form while *submitting it,* you can use [AJAX submitting](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).

Comment: But I am getting the values as expected in my dummy application.I am setting the value using javascript itself.I just want it to be as it is for all the navigations.

Comment: @adn295: then you need to edit your question and show us your code (js + HTML) so that we could help you

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are factually correct (that HTML doesn't normally do what you're asking it to do), but there are a few things you can do to make it work.

First, how things usually work: In order for the second page to get the proper value of the hidden field, you would process it in the server-side component. It sounds like you are redirecting to a new page in the server-side handler. The best way to make this work is to have that server-side handler process the value and attach it to the redirect as a parameter (likely attached to the querystring). Then have some server-side code generate the second page, which would process the querystring parameter.

**Here's the work-around for pure-HTML/javascript implementation**:

If you can't or won't have a server-side process to generate the second page, you could pull it out of the querystring using Javascript (just search for 'getting querystring variables in javascript').

If you use javascript, it could be feasible (though probably not advisable) to have the first form go directly to the second page by setting it as the form's `action` with a `method` of 'GET'. It's definitely better to include a server-side handler though.

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to do is impossible through regular HTML since HTML is stateless. What you want is to put your values in a [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) or in a [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) and this way you can plant it on every page that is loaded.This cannot be done by default.

Answer (score 1):

You're mis-understanding how HTTP works - it is *stateless*.

This means that every single page you request is completely separate to previous pages.  Which is the reason your hidden textbox is being set back to default.

You have to explicitly set the value server side prior to it being sent to the client.